# Bootstrap navbar collapse button unclickable in rails 4, bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using rails 4, bootstrap 3 (bootstrap-sass 3.1.1.1). When I resize my window down the button appears but is not clickable.  My cursor doesn't change when hovering and the button does not change appearance.  When I click nothing happens.

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>site</title>
    <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/campaigns.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/custom.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/scaffolds.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
    <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>
    <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
    <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/users.js?body=1"></script>
    <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/dropdown.js?body=1"></script>
    <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/transition.js?body=1"></script>
    <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap/collapse.js?body=1"></script>
    <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class='navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top' role='navigation'>
      <div class='container-fluid'>
        <div class='navbar-header'>
          <button class='navbar-toggle' data-target='.navbar-collapse' data-toggle='collapse' type='button'>
            <span class='sr-only'>Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class='icon-bar'></span>
            <span class='icon-bar'></span>
            <span class='icon-bar'></span>
          </button>
          <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-left'>
            <li>
              <a href="#" id="logo-navbar"><img alt="Logo" height="27" src="/assets/Logo.png" width="27" /></a>
              <a href='#' id='logo-text'>
                <b>site</b>name
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class='navbar-collapse'>
          <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
            <li><a href="#"><img alt="search" height="15" src="/assets/search-icon.png" width="15" /></a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>about</a></li>
            <li class='dropdown'>
              <a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'>
                sign in
              </a>
              <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                <li><a href='#'>sign in</a></li>
                <li><a href='#'>register</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
@import "bootstrap";
body { padding-top: 55px; } // Padding to make body start after the 50px nabar

// Start Navbar styling
.navbar-default { background-color: white; }
.navbar-nav { margin: 0px }
#logo-navbar { 
    padding:10px 5px; 
    display:inline-block;
}
#logo-text {
    color:black; 
    font-size: 24px; 
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0px;
}
.navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child { margin: auto; }
// End Navbar styling

.navbar .in .nav li {
  display: block;
  float: none;
  width:100%;
}
```

app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:

```
!!!5
%html
    %head
        %title site
        = stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
        = javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true
        = csrf_meta_tags
    %body
        = render 'layouts/header'
        = yield
```

app/assets/javascipt/application.js:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap/dropdown
//= require bootstrap/transition
//= require bootstrap/collapse
```

Comment: Your Bootstrap JavaScript is not loading. What do you have in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb and app/assets/javascipt/application.js? You can compare what you have to the [rails-bootstrap](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-bootstrap) example application and see a tutorial [Rails and Bootstrap](http://railsapps.github.io/twitter-bootstrap-rails.html).

Comment: Updated per your comment.  It looks like the js is loading - am I missing something? I've also tried just requiring bootstrap and it does the same thing.

Comment: Does this work if you take out the custom styles that you added?

Comment: Nope.  Even after pasting in completely stock bootstrap html with no css changes it wouldn't work.  We ended up nixing the collapsable menu completely, but we still never figured it out unfortunately.

Comment: @Demosophy Try removing the `//= require turbolinks` line from `app/assets/javascipt/application.js`.